# how to set pypy in pyspark for windows 10?

Tags: python, windows, apache-spark, pyspark, pypy

I am trying to use pypy instead of ipython, but I getting errors. I have added pypy in system environmental paths. If I add python instead of pypy in environmental paths, everything works perfectly.

I have been stuck at this for a few hours, any help will be appreciated.

```
PS C:\Users\akash> pypy
Python 3.7.4 (87875bf2dfd8, Sep 24 2020, 07:27:16)
[PyPy 7.3.2-alpha0 with MSC v.1927 32 bit] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>>> exit()
```

---

```
PS C:\Users\akash> pyspark
'C:\pypy3.7-v7.3.2-win32\' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

I tried using these commands, but it doesn't do anything.

```
set PYSPARK_PYTHON=C:\pypy3.7-v7.3.2-win32\pypy3.exe
```

Comment: I got it. For some reason, I have to add manually PYSPARK_PYTHON in system variables. Using through cmd set PYSPARK_PYTHON doesn't not work.

Comment: PyPy dev here. Does PyPy run your code faster? Care to share your use case, we are always interested in hearing how PyPy is being used, and invite satisfied users to write blog posts or tweets about their experiences.

Comment: Hey @mattip, I was shocked to see how fast pypy is. pypy is almost 3 times faster than python. I will write a blog post for it on medium. Thanks for your contributions to pypy.

Comment: Cool. Please let me know either here or reach out in some other way so we can be sure to repost/twitter